# read file from folder using stream reader in c#

Tags: c#

Is there any way i can connect to folder and then read files one by one using streamreader(folder containing file is on same machine), i do not want to provide path of file directly in streamreader rather i want to provide path or location of folder where my files are kept, once this is done i want to open a loop and read all files one by one.

Currently i am trying below code however i have to provide filename along with path which i dont want to.

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
```

Please suggest any optimal solution for this,

Thanks
yogendra

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles.aspx - just loop through the files.

Comment: did you tried to google before posting?

Comment: http://www.csharp-examples.net/get-files-from-directory/

Answer (score 1):

You can use Directory.GetFiles http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx

```
var FileList = Directory.GetFiles(DirectoryPath);

foreach (var file in FileList)
{
   StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file);
   // Do some work
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

More info can be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.opentext.aspx

```
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"C:\SomeFolder\");
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

        foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles())
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = fi.OpenText())
            {
                sb.AppendLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
```